# Displaying WMS sublayers on ArcGIS JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms, layers

I want to display layers of a WMS service containing sublayers on ArcGIS using JavaScript 3. No layers appear, but the WMSLayer is marked as loaded.

the WMS is described here:

[data shom WMS](https://services.data.shom.fr/ncwms2/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities)

My code is here :

```
esri.config.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push('https://services.data.shom.fr');

  var layer1 = new WMSLayerInfo({
    name: 'VAGUES_WW3_R1250_MISTRAL-1000M_*',
    title: 'Vagues Mistral'
  });
  var layer2 = new WMSLayerInfo({
    name: 'VAGUES_MFWAM_R0000_GLOB05/Direction_of_wind_waves_msl',
    title: 'Vagues Provence est'
  });
  var resourceInfo = {
    extent: new Extent(2.071094, 42.30868, 7.080859, 44.251969, {
      wkid: 4326
    }),
    layerInfos: [layer1, layer2]
  };

  var wmsLayer = new WMSLayer('https://services.data.shom.fr/ncwms2/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&LAYERS=VAGUES_WW3_R1221_PROVENCE-OUEST-200M/Secondary_wave_mean_period_msl&BBOX=2.071094%2C42.30868%2C7.080859%2C44.251969&TIME=2018-10-10T02:00:00.00Z&WIDTH=1024&HEIGHT=1024&CRS=CRS%3A84', {


visibleLayers:['VAGUES_WW3_R1243_CORSE-EST-200M/Secondary_wave_mean_period_msl','VAGUES_MFWAM_R0000_GLOB05/u0']
  });

  map.addLayers([wmsLayer]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the service response for your snippet, it says:

```
<ServiceException code="OperationNotSupported">
    Only 1 layer may be requested
</ServiceException>
```

Seems like they only allow you to specify one single layer in the `visibleLayers`, for example:

```
visibleLayers:['VAGUES_MFWAM_R0000_GLOB05/u0']
```